# how to restart a handler postdelay process if interupted during delay countdown

Tags: android, handler, counter, runnable, postdelayed

I have a problem that i can't work out. I have a button that when clicked changes the text view. It then activates a `postdelayed` process that returns the `textview` to its original text after 2 seconds.

If i press the button once, and then again within this 2 second interval the `postdelay` will continue to count down from the first press and not restart itself from the second press. This results in the original text being shown when i want the changed text to be.

Each time the button is pressed it creates a delay from that instance. I want it to cancel the previous `postdelay` and start a new one. This is my code so far but its not finished because i can't work out how to finish it (so it does not work).

```
p1AddL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter1 ++;
            count1 ++;
            Handler h = new Handler();
            if ('PREVIOUS_DELAY_HAS_STARTED') {
                h.removeCallbacks(clickButton);
                h.postDelayed(clickButton, 2000);
            } else {
                h.postDelayed(clickButton, 2000);
            }
            if (count1 > 0) {
                lifepointsP1.setText("+" + count1);
                lifepointsP1.setTextColor(Color.argb(220, 0, 188, 0));
            }
        }
    });

Runnable clickButton = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count1 = 0;
        lifepointsP1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lifepointsP1.setText(counter1);
    }
};
```

the `PREVIOUS_DELAY_HAS_STARTED` text needs to be some sort of checking method and i'm pretty sure i need something between the `h.removeCallbacks` and `h.postDelayed` commands under that text.

If their is a simpler way/better way to write this method to make it work please let me know. I have tried so many ways and i feel i am very close here.

Comment: just always call h.removeCallbacks(clickButton);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

removeCallbacks won't do anything if clickButton isn't registered on h. So you can simply replace

```
if ('PREVIOUS_DELAY_HAS_STARTED') {
    h.removeCallbacks(clickButton);
    h.postDelayed(clickButton, 2000);
} else {
    h.postDelayed(clickButton, 2000);
}
```

with

```
h.removeCallbacks(clickButton);
h.postDelayed(clickButton, 2000);
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. although, this has not fixed the problem. I had it like this originally. It still causes a delay countdown to happen on every click and not to cancel the last click and start a new one. Would you guys suggest anything else that could work?

Comment: ok,  so maybe create a Handler once and set it to class field

Comment: Nice, that's the solution. You create a new Handler each time, which of course does not have anything posted to it.

Comment: yes! excatly. Thank you. you both fixed the problem. i have been stuck on this for days!